# assign value to NA's based on index in data table

Tags: r, indexing, data.table

Suppose we have a data table like this:

```
DT <- data.table(x = 1:5, y = c(6, NA, 8, NA, 10), z = 11:15)
> DT
   x  y  z
1: 1  6 11
2: 2 NA 12
3: 3  8 13
4: 4 NA 14
5: 5 10 15
```

I would like to assign the NA values in y to the value in the row above in column z, so the output would be like this:

```
   x  y  z
1: 1  6 11
2: 2 11 12
3: 3  8 13
4: 4 13 14
5: 5 10 15
```

I can do it statically (all NAs will be 15) like this:

```
DT[is.na(y), `:=`(y = DT[5, z])]
```

But I am after something like this (doesn't work):

```
DT[is.na(y), `:=`(y = DT[row-1, z])]
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `replace` and `shift`, i.e.

```
library(data.table)

DT[, y := replace(y, is.na(y), shift(z, type = 'lag')[is.na(y)])][]
```

which gives,

> ```
>    x  y  z
> 1: 1  6 11
> 2: 2 11 12
> 3: 3  8 13
> 4: 4 13 14
> 5: 5 10 15
> ```

We can avoid `replace` as per @Jaap's comment as follows,

```
DT[is.na(y), y := DT[, shift(z, type = 'lag')[is.na(y)]]][]
```

Comment: This works, thanks. But its not very general - what if i want to move two rows up? Also, its a bit difficult to understand.

Comment: `shift` has an `n` argument where you can specify how many rows you want to lag. Default is 1. The `replace` is straight forward I think. So it seeks all the NA in `y` column and `replace`s them with lag 1 `z`

Comment: Without using `replace`: `DT[is.na(y), y := DT[, shift(z, type = 'lag')[is.na(y)]]][]`